# ¿como puedo hacer visible un campo al seleccionar un elemento en un recyclearView?

Tags: android

Hola soy nueva en esto de programar, lo poquito que he logrado ha sido viendo vídeos, pero llegue a un punto donde no se que hacer.

¿como puedo hacer visible un campo al seleccionar un elemento en un recyclearView?

Necesito que el campo fecha sea visible solo en el elemento seleccionado del recyclearView

Necesito que el campo fecha sea visible solo en el elemento seleccionado del 
recyclearView

Necesito que el campo fecha sea visible solo en el elemento seleccionado del recyclearView

No se que poder en el onClick (View v)

Gracias por su ayuda.

```
class Adapter_clientes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_clientes.ViewHolderDatos> {

ArrayList<clientes> lista_clientes;

public Adapter_clientes(ArrayList<clientes> lista_clientes) {
    this.lista_clientes = lista_clientes;
}


@Override
public Adapter_clientes.ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.caratula_cliente,null,false);

    return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_clientes.ViewHolderDatos holder, int 
position) {

    holder.nombre.setText(lista_clientes.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.fecha.setText(lista_clientes.get(position).getFecha());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return lista_clientes.size();

}


public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout caratula_clientes, datos_items;
    TextView nombre, fecha;


    public ViewHolderDatos(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        caratula_clientes = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caratula_clientes);
        datos_items = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.datos_items);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        fecha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (getAdapterPosition() == ???) {

           ??????????
        }



    }
}
```

}

CARATULA.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/caratula_clientes"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/datos_cliente"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:text="nombre"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fecha"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fecha"/>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: El código de tu clase "Clientes" es incorrecto, me parece que le falta una llave de cierre en onClick() ?

Comment: Si, me falto al momento de publicarlo en este blog, gracias Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede realizarse agregando a tu objeto `clientes` la propiedad `seleccionado`, aquí almacenarás si el objeto fue seleccionado o desseleccionado:

```
private int seleccionado;

public int getSeleccionado() {
    return seleccionado;
}

public void setSeleccionado(int seleccionado) {
    this.seleccionado = seleccionado;
}
```

De esta forma puedes registrar si el elemento fue seleccionado y cambiarlo de color,

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selecciono:"+lista_clientes.get(recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getNombre(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      //*Si fue seleccionado previamente lo marca no seleccionado y viceversa.
      if(recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getSeleccionado() == 0){
        recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).setSeleccionado(1);
      }else{
        recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).setSeleccionado(0);
      }     

   }
```

Dentro de tu adapter puedes leer esta propiedad:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_clientes.ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

    holder.nombre.setText(lista_clientes.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.fecha.setText(lista_clientes.get(position).getFecha());

    //Cambia el color dependiendo de la selección.
    if (lista_clientes.get(position).getSeleccionado == 1) {
        holder.caratula_clientes.setBackgroundColor(0xEEEEEEEE);
    }else{
        holder.caratula_clientes.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
}
```

de esta forma no importa que las vistas se destruyan, la propiedad que determina si esta seleccionado se mantendrá.

Comment: Jorgesys gracias por tu tiempo y colaboración, estoy tratando de hacer lo que tu me sugieres, la segunda y tercera parte ya las inserte, pero no doy, donde colocar la primera parte que me sugieres, la coloque en mi clase clientes, pero me genera un error. Que pena, discúlpame la ignorancia.

Comment: La primera parte se agrega en la clase "clientes" que en realidad es un objeto. Que error estás obteniendo? Recuerda siempre comentar el texto del error que obtienes.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, en la siguiente entrada te explico lo que hice y el error que me genera. gracias

Comment: OK @Isabel  si desarrollas en android el uso del LogCat es muy importante, que error se muestra ?

Comment: Buen día, el error lo copie en la ultima entrada, pero la entrada la borraron. Error mostrado: Error:(46, 61) error: int cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: @Isabel ah ya esta en tu pregunta,donde deben agregarse las ediciones, edita tu pregunta y agrega como modificaste el onClick por favor.

Comment: Que pena Jorgesys  pensaba que las preguntas no se podían editar luego de ser publicadas o atendidas por alguien.